# Convergence of harmonic functions.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am looking for the proof of the following Theorem : Does anyone know where i can find out ?

If $\Omega$ is open and connected and $u_k$ be uniformly bounded sequence of harmonic functions . There exists a subsequence that converges uniformly to a harmonic function $u:\Omega \to \mathbb R$ on any compact subset of $\Omega$.

In case you think that its not hard, i look forward to hints as well.

I hope the statement is true . 
Thanks.

Comment: You can add a constant to make them all $\ge 1$, and apply Harnack's inequality to get equicontinuity on compact subsets... then Arzela-Ascoli.

Comment: @LeonidKovalev : Sir, i was thinking of using derivative bound of harmonic equation but before using it how do i set up so that i can use it ?

Comment: That works too. If $z\in\Omega$, then there exists $r>0$ such that the disk $D(z,r)$ is contained in $\Omega$, and you have an upper bound on $|\nabla u_k|$ in $D(z,r/2)$. Hence the family is locally uniformly Lipschitz, which implies equicontinuity on compact subsets as well.

Answer (score 7):

See theorem 2.6 in the page 35 [here](http://www.axler.net/HFT.pdf) and the comment below.

Answer (score 2):

You can see this book

D.H. Armitage, S.J. Gardiner, Classical Potential Theory, Springer, London, 2000.

proposition 1.5.11. This will exactly answer your question.
This is a link of [this book](http://books.google.tn/books?hl=fr&lr=&id=02p9FQ41o9cC&oi=fnd&pg=PR13&dq=D.H.+Armitage,+S.J.+Gardiner,+Classical+Potential+Theory,+Springer,+London,+2000.&ots=q00AwjQRLS&sig=yH2t_51iHIpObjJTfAzD5zaydmg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=D.H.%20Armitage%2C%20S.J.%20Gardiner%2C%20Classical%20Potential%20Theory%2C%20Springer%2C%20London%2C%202000.&f=false) in booksgoogle

Enjoy.

Comment: Can you quote the proposition? We can't see it in booksgoogle.